# Is there a function to check a set of events/random variables are mutually independent?

Tags: r, probability, independence

Say, 5 random variables A,B,C,D,E which can take values either 0 or 1.

I have the theoretical population chances for the 32 cases of P(A,B,C,D,E). Obviously they add up to 1.

How to check if A,B,C,D,E are mutually independent.

```
 0 0 0 1 0   ->   0.039026946
 0 0 0 0 0   ->   0.221152694
 0 0 0 0 1   ->   0.000000000
 0 0 0 1 1   ->   0.000000000
 0 0 1 0 0   ->   0.081381771
 0 0 1 0 1   ->   0.000000000
 0 0 1 1 0   ->   0.014361489
 0 0 1 1 1   ->   0.000000000
 0 1 0 0 0   ->   0.126588070
 0 1 0 0 1   ->   0.000000000
 0 1 0 1 0   ->   0.022339071
 0 1 0 1 1   ->   0.000000000
 0 1 1 0 0   ->   0.046583025
 0 1 1 0 1   ->   0.000000000
 0 1 1 1 0   ->   0.008220534
 0 1 1 1 1   ->   0.000000000
 1 0 0 0 0   ->   0.174007266
 1 0 0 0 1   ->   0.000000000
 1 0 0 1 0   ->   0.030707165
 1 0 0 1 1   ->   0.000000000
 1 0 1 0 0   ->   0.064032769
 1 0 1 0 1   ->   0.000000000
 1 0 1 1 0   ->   0.011299900
 1 0 1 1 1   ->   0.000000000
 1 1 0 0 0   ->   0.099601970
 1 1 0 0 1   ->   0.000000000
 1 1 0 1 0   ->   0.017576818
 1 1 0 1 1   ->   0.000000000
 1 1 1 0 0   ->   0.036652435
 1 1 1 0 1   ->   0.000000000
 1 1 1 1 0   ->   0.006468077
 1 1 1 1 1   ->   0.000000000
```

Comment: This might seem to be not very revealing, but there's already software available to do the check: conduct a chi-squared test (in the five-way table) and check that the chi-squared statistic is exactly zero. Incidentally, aren't there really just four variables here?  The fifth is certain to equal 0 and so is just a constant.

Comment: @whuber I don't think we need the chi-squared test as the one I provide with are the exact theoretical population probabilities, but not the observations.

Comment: I understand that: that's why I'm not proposing you refer the statistic to a chi-square distribution. I'm saying you need the statistic to be *exactly* zero. That's tantamount to absolutely perfect independence.

Comment: @whuber I am not sure if the statistic to be 0 is both sufficient & necessary condition of the variables to be independent. But if it does, it is a good approach

Comment: @whuber is correct. Think about what independence of probabilities requires, and then think about what the 'expecteds' would be in a chi-square, and what a 0 chi-square then implies about the relationship between the values you give above and the expecteds. It's not the *only* way to do it, and it's not necessarily the most *algebraically* direct or perhaps the most immediately obvious way to do it (at least until you come to understand why it works), but it's built in to almost any stats package worth the name, and so it's going to be a very *easy* way to do it.

Comment: I do not claim to be a statistician nor do I play one on the Internet, but if your list has the _exact_ probabilities instead of data obtained by simulation, then _at least in this instance_, an **eyeball** test shows that $E$ is independent of the other random variables since the joint probability $P(A,B,C,D,E)$ equals $0$ whenever $E=1$. So it suffices to check independence of $A,B,C,D$ only which can be done by finding the marginal mass functions (column sums!) and verifying that $$p_{A,B,C,D}(a,b,c,d)=p_A(a)p_B(b)p_C(c)p_D(d), a,b,c,d \in \{0,1\}$$ on all $16$ nonzero rows of your table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiway chi-square test computes the marginal chances of each variable and compares the given chances to the products of the marginal chances: by definition, the variables are independent if and only if every one of the joint chances equals the product of the marginal chances.  Thus, if we convert this information into the format expected by your statistical software's contingency table independence test, all we need do is verify that the chi-squared statistic is zero.  This is sufficient because the chi-squared statistic is a sum of squares of residuals; when it is zero, every residual must be zero, whence independence holds.

---

Here is an example in `R`.  It multiplies all the probabilities by a sufficiently large number to make them all integral, which is what a chi-squared test assumes it will be given (it "thinks" these are counts).

```
m = matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.039026946,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.221152694,
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.081381771,
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0.014361489,
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.12658807,
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0.022339071,
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.046583025,
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.008220534,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.174007266,
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.030707165,
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.064032769,
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0.0112999,
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.09960197,
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0.017576818,
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.036652435,
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.006468077,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), nrow=6)

data <- data.frame(t(m))
xt <- xtabs(~ X1+X2+X3+X4+X5, data=data)
xt[1:32] <- data$X6 * 10^8
    summary(xt)$statistic
```

The output is zero, confirming independence.

Comment: you can use `xtabs(X6 * 10^8~ X1+X2+X3+X4+X5, data=data)` However there is an issue: since X5 = 0 always, the statistic is NA. I have to exclude X5 in the table